# Why can I not center an "a" tag inside a Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue getting the `<a href>` tags I use as buttons in my three Bootstrap columns to center when I set an absolute `width` to them, as well as setting `position:absolute;` in my CSS Style sheet.

Can anyone see what I'm missing out here? Here's what I have so far.

What I currently have:

```css
.outer-row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.dark-bar-option-col {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  align-content: center!important;
  text-align: center!important;
}
.dark-bar-option-col a {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #3A83F3;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
.dark-bar-option-col a:hover {
  background-color: #0D5C9E;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dark-bar-option-col:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: #E0DDDD;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 outer-row">
      <div class="col-md-4 dark-bar-option-col">
        <a href="#">Find out more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 dark-bar-option-col">
        <a href="#">This is a button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 dark-bar-option-col">
        <a href="#">This is a button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can not expect them to be centered when they are in col-md-4. Secondly, remove position: absolute. Do you need them aligned center vertically, horizontally or both?

```css
.outer-row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.dark-bar-option-col {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  align-content: center!important;
  text-align: center!important;
}
.dark-bar-option-col a {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #3A83F3;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
.dark-bar-option-col a:hover {
  background-color: #0D5C9E;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dark-bar-option-col:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: #E0DDDD;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 outer-row">
      <div class="dark-bar-option-col">
        <a href="#">Find out more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="dark-bar-option-col">
        <a href="#">This is a button</a>
      </div>
      <div class="dark-bar-option-col">
        <a href="#">This is a button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need them centered both horizontally and vertically use this:

```
CSS:
.outer-row {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.dark-bar-option-col {
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
 align-content: center!important;
text-align: center!important;

}
.xcent{ position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
 .dark-bar-option-col a {
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #3A83F3;
 color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 font-size: 12px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;

 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 200px;
 }
.dark-bar-option-col a:hover {
background-color: #0D5C9E;
text-decoration: none;
 }
.dark-bar-option-col:nth-child(2) {
 border-left: solid;
 border-right: solid;
 border-color: #E0DDDD;
border-width: 3px;
}

HTML:

<div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 outer-row">
  <div class="dark-bar-option-col">
    <div class="xcent">
    <a href="#">Find out more</a>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="dark-bar-option-col">
    <div class="xcent">
    <a href="#">This is a button</a>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="dark-bar-option-col">
    <div class="xcent">
    <a href="#">This is a button</a>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a position absolute on your anchor.
Just ad a left position ( 50%) and set negative left margin half of your anchor size (-100px)

Do this:

```
.dark-bar-option-col a {
    background-color: #3a83f3;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px -100px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px -100px;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/218/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since the container has no fixed width and your anchor is absolute, you can't center like this. You could use `CSS Transform` for this on your anchor element.

```
.dark-bar-option-col a{
padding: 15px;
background-color: #3A83F3;
color: white;
bottom: 0;
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
margin: 20px;
width:200px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```css
.outer-row{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 1px;
position: relative;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.dark-bar-option-col{
padding: 5px;
position:relative;
height: 100%;
align-content: center!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
.dark-bar-option-col a{
padding: 15px;
background-color: #3A83F3;
color: white;
bottom: 0;
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
margin: 20px;
width:200px;
/*-- Added --*/
transform: translateX(-50%);
margin-left: 50%;
}
.dark-bar-option-col a:hover{
background-color: #0D5C9E;
text-decoration: none;
}
.dark-bar-option-col:nth-child(2){
border-left: solid;
border-right: solid;
border-color: #E0DDDD;
border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 outer-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 dark-bar-option-col">
                <a href="#">Find out more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 dark-bar-option-col">
                <a href="#">This is a button</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 dark-bar-option-col">
                <a href="#">This is a button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to make something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/gvsd6kvr/1/)

```
.dark-bar-option-col a{
padding: 15px;
background-color: #3A83F3;
color: white;
/* bottom: 0; */
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
/* margin: 20px; */
width:200px;

/* added */
bottom:0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  your problem is that you are positioning it absolute, try removing that line and also, don't give it a margin of 20px, instead use  "0 auto". this will give it an automatic witdth for the left and right with 0px for top and bottom.

Try this:

```
.dark-bar-option-col a{
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #3A83F3;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:200px;
}
```